# Get all models in backbone collection where attribute is NOT equal to some value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is taken from the Backbone.js documentation:

```
var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
```

Where you can get an array of models where job is equal is "Musketeer". But how do I do the opposite? How can I get an array of models where job is anything else but "Musketeer"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know of something that's a direct opposite, but you can use a [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) to the same effect.

```
var notMusketeers = friends.filter(function (friend) {
  return friend.job !== 'Musketeer';
});
```

Comment: Technically, filter does not return models.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `filter` directly on a Backbone collection, you must use it this way:

```
var notMusketeers = friends.filter(function(model){
    return model.get('job') !== 'Musketeer';
});
```

Then `notMusketeers` will be an array of Backbone model instances.

If `friends` is just an array of objects (standard collection), you could use the underscore `filter` this way:

```
var notMusketeers = _.filter(friends, function(obj){
    return obj.job !== 'Musketeer';
});
```

### ES6

If ES6+ features are available to you, `const`, destructuring and arrow functions could make it a little less verbose:

```
const notMusketeers = friends.filter(({ job }) => job !== 'Musketeer');
```