# How to get elements from object where in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have object-model as:

```
var wo = new WordModel({
    "url": window.location.href,
    "time": toDay(),
    "w": w.trim()
});

timelineCollection.add(wo);
```

I try to get all element in `timelineCollection` where `time` is `04/02/2017`. I tried this:

```
var o = {
    time: "04/02/2017"
};

var filtered = timelineCollection.where(o);
console.log(filtered);
```

But it does not work for me

Comment: This is unrelated to Backbone unless the code shown here is not the one in your app. Also, this is not valid JavaScript syntax. It looks like `obj` should be an array, is this correct? Are you looking for answer with Underscore? or plain JavaScript?

Comment: This is code from console.log in console

Comment: You should read about [mcve] and edit your question. Also, look for similar questions in [tag:underscore.js] as most are exactly about this.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: What's the result of `toDay()`?

Comment: Could help: [Get all models in backbone collection where attribute is NOT equal to some value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608254/get-all-models-in-backbone-collection-where-attribute-is-not-equal-to-some-value)

Comment: Is string: "04/02/2017"

Comment: Without a [mcve] of the problem, we won't be able to help you solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's collection [`where` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) is really what you should use for this.

```js
// short syntax, every object becomes a Backbone.Model by default.
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{
    id: 0,
    time: "04/02/2017",
  }, {
    id: 1,
    time: "05/02/2017",
  },
  // you can mix both plain objects and Model instances
  new Backbone.Model({
    id: 2,
    time: "04/07/2017",
  }), new Backbone.Model({
    id: 3,
    time: "04/02/2017",
  })
]);

// passing an existing model works too.
var model = new Backbone.Model({
  id: 4,
  time: "04/02/2017",
});

collection.add(model);

console.log(collection.where({
  time: "04/02/2017"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems problem is that I use model, and t first fill model after add to collection

Comment: @Darama nope, my answer only uses a shorter syntax.

Comment: @Darama the problem is likely not shown in your question, possibly `toDay()` is not returning what you think or your `WordModel` is not a child class of `Backbone.Model`.

Comment: I added `toDay()` function in question